# If $a\in\text{Inv}\mathcal{A}~$ And $~b\in\mathcal{A}~;~\|a-b\|\leq\frac{\|a\|^{2}}{\|a^{-1}\|}$ then $~b\in\text{Inv}\mathcal{A}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

---

Exercices :

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a banach algebra , $a\in\text{Inv}\mathcal{A}~$ And $~b\in\mathcal{A}$

Suppose that :

$$\|a-b\|<\frac{\|a\|^{2}}{\|a^{-1}\|}$$

Then prove that :

1. $~~~~b\in\text{Inv}\mathcal{A}$
2. $~~||b^{-1}-a^{-1}||\leq\frac{||a^{-1}||^{2}~||b-a||}{1-||a^{-1}||~||b-a||}$$

---

**My attempts**

I can't show the fist question but I have I try for Second

If $~~b\in\text{Inv}\mathcal{A}$ then
$b=a-(a-b)=a(e-a^{-1}(a-b))$
invertible and :

$$b^{-1}=[e-a^{-1}(a-b)]^{-1}a^{-1}$$
$$~~~~~~=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(a^{-1}(a-b))^{n}a^{-1}$$
$\implies b^{-1}-a^{-1}=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a^{-1}(a-b))^{n}a^{-1}$
$$\implies \|b^{-1}-a^{-1}\|=||a^{-1}(a-b)||~||a^{-1}||\frac{1}{1-||a^{-1}(a-b)||}$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\leq\frac{||a^{-1}||^{2}~||b-a||}{1-||a^{-1}||~||b-a||}$$
....so I need a help for fist questions!!

---

**Thanks for your time**

Comment: There seems to be typo but I cannot figure out what change is needed on RHS.

Comment: If $a$ is invertibleand $\|a-b\|<1/\|a^{-1}\|$ then also $b$is invertible. Reduce to the case $a=e$ and use the Neumann series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (e-b)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is wrong. If $b=0$ and $a=2e$ then  $\|a-b\|=2$ and $\frac {\|a\|^{2}} {\|a^{-1}\|}=\frac  4 {1/2}=8>\|a-b\|$ but $b$ is not invertible.